# Can I disable "require certificate" on a single service in an app pool?

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-7, certificate

I have an IIS-7 app pool that is publicly available with SSL "Require client certificates" enabled. I need to stand up a new WCF service in that same project/webSite but need to disable the client certificate requirement on that page, in order to do application-level authentication. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration in web.config

```
<location path="relative_path_to_service.svc">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <access sslFlags="Ssl" />
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

You might need to modify applicationHost.config like this:

```
<section name="access" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

It is in `c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config` directory. I have not tried it with WCF but It worked in MVC application where I wanted to set a subpage to require certificate mode but the rest of the application remained SSL only.